# This Terminal Emulator is not functional because no 'bash' shell could be found. Please correct the problem and restart the IDE

Tags: terminal, aptana

I use Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.2.201106082310 on Arch Linux x86_64, I also have git version 1.7.6 installed.
This is the error found in .log:

```
!ENTRY com.aptana.terminal 1 0 2011-07-09 14:59:44.114
!MESSAGE Starting terminal process failed.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/share/aptana/plugins/com.aptana.terminal_3.0.0.1306201824/os/linux/x86_64/redtty" (in directory "/home/kasper/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/sarkasper.github.com"): java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at com.aptana.terminal.internal.ProcessLauncher.launch(ProcessLauncher.java:42)
    at com.aptana.terminal.connector.LocalTerminalConnector.startProcess(LocalTerminalConnector.java:206)
    at com.aptana.terminal.connector.LocalTerminalConnector.access$0(LocalTerminalConnector.java:196)
    at com.aptana.terminal.connector.LocalTerminalConnector$1.run(LocalTerminalConnector.java:95)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:148)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 8):

It might be a P2 installation issue. Try `chmod +x usr/share/aptana/plugins/com.aptana.terminal_3.0.0.1306201824/os/linux/x86_64/redtty`

Cheers,
Max

Comment: How did you install Aptana Studio?

Comment: I used [Yaourt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yaourt), the Arch Linux user repository tool to install it with the PKGBUILD here: http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=31634, but I had to update the PKGBUILD with the url of Aptana v.3.0.3, as well as the md5sum of the zip package.

Comment: How did you figure out this answer?! It worked perfectly but I just don't see how I could / would have debugged this on my own!

Comment: The error says "Cannot run program... Permission denied" so it was obvious. Plus I'm Aptana Studio developer ;)

Answer (score 0):

~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/plugins/com.aptana.terminal_3.0.0.1306201824/os/linux/x86_x64/redtty was the path on my debian machine using eclipse 3.8 with the Aptana Studio plugin.

Comment: This issue occurred for me because I migrated old configuration files in  my home folder from one machine to another and didn't have the right permissions afterwards.