# Terminal not working in Aptana IDE with OSX

Tags: macos, aptana, aptana3

> This Terminal Emulator is not functional because no 'bash' shell could be found.
>   Please correct the problem and restart the ID

This is a brand new OSX laptop with 10.13.6, and I've been trying to replicate the setup with aptana 3. I'm not sure what I'm missing to be getting this error... previous threads with similar errors all seem to be dealing with windows environments

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on macOS Mojave 10.14 with AptanaStudio 3.7.2 and could fix it based on the suggestion here (which is for linux) https://stackoverflow.com/a/6685532/5220160

So assuming your AptanaStudio.app sits in /Applications the fix would be `chmod +x /Applications/AptanaStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/com.aptana.terminal_3.0.0.201802081530/os/macosx/redtty`